# Where should I ask questions about location based E-commerce websites?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Please let me know where can I ask questions about E-commerce sites? For example I want to know: Is there any E-commerce website or startup which is equally popular in United States as well as Japan,China?

Comment: Could you please ask a specific question? If this question represents the type of question you are going to ask on any of the SE sites. I say don't. So to answer your question: not here on SE.

Comment: How would you even define "equally popular in United States as well as Japan, China"? I call "troll".

Comment: Nowhere. That's just **not a good question**.

Answer (score 7):

Your example is a bad question & won't last anywhere on the network

Comment: Gee, you posted the same thing I did in a comment, but you earned 60 sparkly unicorn points for it. Don't I look dumb! I always want to say things like this, but think they're too harsh, so I chicken out and leave a comment instead...

Comment: @TheEstablishment D'awwww. Thankz for dem unicorn points, they be tasty. Om Nom Nom Nom